# How do we create connection in JAVA using glassfish server

Tags: mysql, netbeans-7

I require all the steps required to establish link with mysql database with JAVA code. Using glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target is to develop an EE application which is to be deployed in Glassfish. Then your application will inject an EntityManager whose transaction type is "JTA".

Follow these steps to setup your JTA transaction type:

Copy your MySQL driver jar into the folder: ..\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib

Open glassfish admin console

Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Connection Pools

Push new button

Pool name*: MySqlPool

Skip Resource type for now

Database Driver Vendor: MySql

Push Next button

DataSource class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Add the following properties:

URL= jdbc:mysql:[type your ServerName]:[type your Port]

User = [type it]

Password = [type it]

Push Finish

Push Ping -> Ping succeeds

Open Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Resources

JNDI Name*: MySqlJNDI

Pool name: MySqlPool

Push OK

In your application persistence.xml, modify it as follows:

```
persistence-unit name="ShivenUnitName" transaction-type="JTA"

<jta-data-source>MySqlJNDI</jta-data-source>
```